# How to center navigation bar in UL?

Tags: css

Tried `display: inline-block; text-align: center;` and many things from the Internet, but nothing helped.

```
#nav{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #C9C9C9;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ddd; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left; }
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px;
     font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000; 
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -khtml-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; }
```

HTML:

```
    <ul  id="nav">
            <?php wp_nav_menu('menu=header_menu&container=false'); ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
   </ul>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

... and I don't know how to center it.

Comment: basic is : ul {margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none;text-align:center;} li {display:inline-block;} , if li floats, you loose :)

Comment: The only element allowed directly inside a `<ul>` is a `<li>`!

Comment: Goddamn, this it it! Post it as the answer and I'll mark it :)

Comment: done! +1 for question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

basic is :

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Note** that if `<li>` floats, you lose :)

http://jsfiddle.net/KWG2j/

then , if you need to center ul with fluid width: go one step higher in html.
http://jsfiddle.net/KWG2j/1

```
nav {
    text-align:center;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #C9C9C9;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
nav li {
    display:inline-block;
}
nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed width on your UL, then adjust it's margin as

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

This will apply equal margins to both the left and right of block elements that have a definite width.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Be4Q2/

```css
#nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #C9C9C9;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline-block;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```